# Lightning component linking salesforce lightning design system

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to use the lightning design system into a lightning component so I can use the grid system.
My problem is for installing the lighning design system : I went [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/) and downolad the "Design System Zip" . I went into my salesforce organization and put this folder into my static ressources (and the MIME type is    application/x-zip-compressed).

Then in my component i put `<ltng:require styles="/resource/slds100/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css"/>`

Here is a part of my code (lightning component):

```
<aura:component controller="ActuliteImageController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

<ltng:require scripts="/resource/jqueryMin,/resource/bootstrapMinJs"
              styles="/resource/bootstrapMin, /resource/slds100/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="act" type="Act__c[]"/>

<div class="slds-grid">
  <span class="slds-badge slds-theme--inverse">Label</span>
    <div class="conteneur slds-col slds-size--1-of-1">
        <aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.act}">
            <div class="article slds-col slds-size--1-of-1">
            some text and image
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>

</div>
```

I tested that with the span tab "label" but it's not working, the style is not applied, neither the grid.

In the browser explorator , in the tab sources I open the folder "ressource" and then I can see another folder "slds100/assets/styles" in which I can see the sheet "salesforce-lightning-design-system.css". When I click on it, the window stay empty as if the css sheet is empty...

What I am doing wrong ? How do you do for installing lightning design system ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a badge for that! Trailhead has a great [unit](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-1) that walks you through the process. To simplify the install you can go [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/) and install it as a managed package.

> Step 2 - Install the SLDS Unmanaged Package
>
> The easiest way to get started is to install the latest Salesforce
>   Lightning Design System unmanaged package, which includes the Design
>   System as a static resource zip file.
>
> Log in to your developer org
>
> In a separate browser window, go to the Salesforce Lightning Design
>   System [downloads](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/) page, look under the Design System Unmanaged Packages
>   section, and click on the latest unmanaged package. Press Install to
>   install it. This will install the package in your Salesforce org. The
>   unmanaged package includes the Salesforce Lightning Design System as a
>   static resource zip file

Comment: thaank you, sorry I don't know why I don't try to install it with Unmanaged Packaged but I think It's working now !

Comment: It's not been deprecated, unfortunately.